# Why do I get a Type Error with this code in python?

Tags: python

```
def word(longest):
   max_length = 0;
   words = longest.split(" ")
   for x in words:
      if len(words[x]) >  max_length:
        max_length = len(words[x])

   return max_length

word("Hello world")
```

Exact Error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Im still a noob at this so please, no mean comments.

Comment: x is the word, not the position of the word in your list words

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using `x` as index, when it is actually the string itself.

You can do:

```
for x in words:
      if len(x) >  max_length:
        max_length = len(x)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do `for x in words`, `x` is a word. So you don't need `words[x]` to get the word. `words[x]` expects `x` to be an integer, but it's a string, which is why you get that error.

So you should write:

```
for x in words:
    if len(x) >  max_length:
        max_length = len(x)
```